# Get Oracle Database name

Tags: c#, oracle

How can I programmatically get the name of the Oracle database I am connecting to? I tried:

```
using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(oraConnectStr))
            {
                connection.Open();
                return connection.Database;
            }
```

but it returns empty string. I can't use the whole connection string because it may contain username/password.

Comment: Have you not tried regexing the connection string? Alternatively, build a proper parser for the connection string (which winds up looking a lot like flattened XML), and read the string off that way. I'm unfamiliar with C#, but that would be a cross-platform/cross-technology way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could query  `v$database`:

```
SQL> SELECT NAME FROM v$database;

NAME
---------
PROD
```

Comment: And supposing he can't connect to the database?! This problem is solvable without a network connection, no?

Answer (score 6):

Not every user has access to the V$ views.  But everybody can run this:

```
SQL> select * from global_name
  2  /

GLOBAL_NAME
---------------------------------------------------
ORCL

SQL>
```

**edit**

If you want to solve this from inside c#, [this article shows how to solve it through the ConnectionString](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/756230-get-database-name-connectionstring).

Answer (score 0):

You can use OracleConnectionStringBuilder object.

OracleConnectionStringBuilder connStrBuilder = 
      new OracleConnectionStringBuilder(oraConnectStr);

connStrBuilder.DataSource will contain your information.

Check out:
http://download.oracle.com/docs/html/E10927_01/OracleConnectionStringBuilderClass.htm#CHDHBCDA